# Can I send multiple ShellToast notifications at once?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

What happens, if I send multiple **ShellToast** notifications from background agent at once, for example in ToDo list app I want to notify that 3 tasks should be finished today?
Is it allowed or recommended? Would the user see all three toasts or only the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scheduled agent only runs once and it's up to you to manage which toast will be shown. In those scenarios you should be using a counter...possibly.

The way I've worked around this sort of thing in the past is just track a time or which toasts have been shown in sort of a queue and just show one every update so you could just rotate through your queue throughout the day until the tasks in app are no longer valid. Or, based on the phone's time, determine what to show (they fire every 30 min or so).

Ultimately, the optimal way is probably having one toast that says "You have 3 tasks to complete" etc etc.

Hope one of those solutions might help!

// Jed

Comment: yeah, I guess sending one notification each time Background Agent runs, or sending aggregated notification "you have x new emails" is probably the best solution.